# PHP MVC: Best Practice and Right way for print data validation error

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have Php Login system using MVC structure. For database data validation I create `LoginModel`. I need to print failure error to `view` like: `User Not Exist` Now Which way is right and better:

**1**- Add error data validation in `Login Model` and get in `Controller` and Print to `View` Like This:

```
class LoginModel extends \App\Core\Model
{
    public function login($user_name, $user_password, $set_remember_me_cookie = null)
    {
        $returnError = array();

            // checks if user exists, if login is not blocked (due to failed logins) and if password fits the hash
            $result = $this->validateAndGetUser($user_name, $user_password);

            // check if that user exists. 
            if (!$result) {
               $returnError['isMessage'] = false;
               $returnError['name'] = "User Not Found";
            }

        return $returnError;
    }
    private function validateAndGetUser($user_name, $user_password){
      //Check User Data Validation
    }
}
```

2- Add Only `True` Or `False` in `LoginModel` and Get in `Controller` And `Set` Error Name and Print to `View` Like This:

```
class LoginModel extends \App\Core\Model
{
    public function login($user_name, $user_password, $set_remember_me_cookie = null)
    {

            // checks if user exists, if login is not blocked (due to failed logins) and if password fits the hash
            $result = $this->validateAndGetUser($user_name, $user_password);

            // check if that user exists. 
            if (!$result) {
                return false;
            }

        return true;
    }
    private function validateAndGetUser($user_name, $user_password){
      //Check User Data Validation
    }
}
```

In action my really question is: Can I add error message in `Model` and Get in `Controller`?! Which way is right and true?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.
For me the best way is the first way you have suggested, but better declare bug reports in a single file eg errors.php and make the model return you array with 2 keys, the first key is always TRUE or FALSE and then if your model returns the first key FALSE reads the error number from the second key.
Then, in the controller you can replace the error number with the corresponding key in the array you declared in errors.php
If the first key is TRUE, then the second key will be your user information.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

Split the login functionality into two (main) steps:

- Check if the posted user already exists. If not, **throw an exception**.
- Match the posted password against the stored one. If they don't match, **throw an exception**. I suggest the use of [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for storing passwords, and of [password_verify](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for matching a password with the stored one.

Then - based on your current architecture, in your controller, use a *try-catch* block to catch the exception thrown by the login steps and proceed as you wish to display the exception message to the user.

Just as a note: In case of an [ajax request](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you would send a *specific* [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Headers_2) (with status code 500, for example) or a *custom* [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Headers_2) (with status code 420, for example) back to the client, e.g. browser, in order to activate the **error** function of the ajax request.

**Notes:**

- The domain model is a [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000). And it must have no knowledge about the outside world.
- A controller should only (!) **update the domain model** (through *services*).
- A view **should be a class** - not a template file - responsible with **fetching data from the model layer** (through *services*), **preparing/formatting** it for presentation, and passing it to a **response object**, in order for this to be returned and printed.
- The controller and the view (mostly 1:1 relation) should be **created separately**. The controller should not have any knowledge about the view. This creation step would take place in the front-controller class or file.
- As for error reporting, I would recommend to read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).